# ASP.NET MVC 3 Binding to a Collection inside an Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model with an object that contains a collection like this:

```
namespace API.Example.Models
{
    public class OrderTest
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string Token { get; set; }

        public POCO.Order Order { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace Supertext.API.POCO
{
    public class Order
    {
        public List<TranslationGroup> Groups = new List<TranslationGroup>();
    }


    public class TranslationGroup
    {
        public string GroupId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Order object contains a collection called Groups.
In the view I display the collection like this (with the index like explained in several examples)

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Order.Groups.Count; i++)
{ 
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Order.Groups[i].GroupId)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Order.Groups[i].GroupId)
}
```

And this is the Controller method that gets called:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Models.OrderTest model)
```

The HTML of the UserName element:

```
<input id="UserName" name="UserName" style="width:300px;" type="text" value="">
```

and the GroupId element:

```
<input id="Order_Groups_0__GroupId" name="Order.Groups[0].GroupId" type="text" value="1">
```

I can access the UserName, but there is nothing in the collection.
What am I missing?
And whats the difference between using m.UserName and Model.Order.Groups (I mean m and Model). Is that my issue?

Comment: Can you put in your question your object that you use in you view? And the generated html for this part?

Comment: Did the html for the GroupId, can post more if necessary.

Comment: Post the html generated to the textbox UserName too, plx.

Comment: What is Groups?  What is it defined as?  Post your Order definition

Comment: Added the UserName HTML and the Order definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each property of POCO entity use like a property managed by the CLR. Let the CLR manage the create of instance and etc.. or you can generate conflicts that can throw issues like you have.

Change your Order code to this:

```
public class Order     
{         
    public List<TranslationGroup> Groups { get; set; }    
}
```

--EDIT

I create a new project and add the following class:

```
public class TranslationGroup
{
    public string GroupId { get; set; } 
}

public class Order
{
    public List<TranslationGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class OrderTest 
{ 
    public string UserName { get; set; } 
    public string Token { get; set; } 
    public Order Order { get; set; } 
}
```

Here my code behind of the OrderTestController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var orderTest = new Models.OrderTest()
    {
        UserName = "Vinicius",
        Token = "12as1da58sd558",
        Order = new Models.Order()
        {
            Groups = new List<Models.TranslationGroup>()
            {
                new Models.TranslationGroup() { GroupId = "a54s"},
                new Models.TranslationGroup() { GroupId = "a87d"},
                new Models.TranslationGroup() { GroupId = "2gf4"}
            }
        }
    };


    return View(orderTest);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Models.OrderTest model)
{
    return View();
}
```

And Index View:

```
@model TestCollection.Models.OrderTest
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>OrderTest</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Token)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Token)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Token)
        </div>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Order.Groups.Count; i++)
        {     
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Order.Groups[i].GroupId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Order.Groups[i].GroupId)
            </div>
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

So, if you run, and go to OrderTest view, you 'll see all attributes filled, and when you click in create, all things will be binded (the collection as well).

Comment: I'm leaving now, but when i reach my home, i'll create a test project with you models.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually tried a simple model, with the collection directly inside the mode and I still have the same issue. Maybe there is something else that I'm doing wrong....

Comment: Sorry for let you standing up, i'll post my answer now, that works fine.

Comment: I'm feeling pretty stupid right now.... I didn't add the { get; set; }   behind the Groups list.